# JavaFX slider with 2 pointers

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, slider, tableview

I have a question. Is it possible to make slider in JavaFX that will have 2 pointers? For example I would use to filter the list. It would be responsible of filtering the list where values match values between 2 pointer.
Or filter the prices between two pointers.

How I can achieve such effect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no range slider available in JavaFX, but you can use the [RangeSlider](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/RangeSlider.html) from ControlsFX Project.